# Opendaylight flourine creating reactive flows

Tags: opendaylight, openflow

I was trying to set up the ODL with mininet using the latest version of ODL which I downloaded from their site. It seems that they have removed support for DELUX but I am using NextUI for it. But I am not able to install the feature `odl-l2switch-switch` or the `odl-l2switch-switch-ui`. It seems to be no longer available.  Is there any other way to enable the reactive flow discovery feature in the ODL. I have been trying to find a solution for a while now.

```
opendaylight-user@root>feature:install odl-l2switch-switch
Error executing command: No matching features for odl-l2switch-switch/0.0.0
opendaylight-user@root>feature:list |grep l2switch
```

I was not able to get a reactive flow entry after connecting to the controller.

```
mininet@mininet-vm:~$ sudo mn --topo=tree,2,2 --controller=remote,ip=10.5.1.3,port=6633 --switch=ovsk,pr
otocol=OpenFlow13
*** Creating network
*** Adding controller
*** Adding hosts:
h1 h2 h3 h4
*** Adding switches:
s1 s2 s3
*** Adding links:
(s1, s2) (s1, s3) (s2, h1) (s2, h2) (s3, h3) (s3, h4)
*** Configuring hosts
h1 h2 h3 h4
*** Starting controller
c0
*** Starting 3 switches
s1 s2 s3 ...
*** Starting CLI:
mininet> links
s1-eth1<->s2-eth3 (OK OK)
s1-eth2<->s3-eth3 (OK OK)
s2-eth1<->h1-eth0 (OK OK)
s2-eth2<->h2-eth0 (OK OK)
s3-eth1<->h3-eth0 (OK OK)
s3-eth2<->h4-eth0 (OK OK)
mininet> pingall
*** Ping: testing ping reachability
h1 -> X X X
h2 -> X X X
h3 -> X X X
h4 -> X X X
*** Results: 100% dropped (0/12 received)
mininet> dump
<Host h1: h1-eth0:10.0.0.1 pid=29639>
<Host h2: h2-eth0:10.0.0.2 pid=29641>
<Host h3: h3-eth0:10.0.0.3 pid=29643>
<Host h4: h4-eth0:10.0.0.4 pid=29645>
<OVSSwitch{'protocol': 'OpenFlow13'} s1: lo:127.0.0.1,s1-eth1:None,s1-eth2:None pid=29650>
<OVSSwitch{'protocol': 'OpenFlow13'} s2: lo:127.0.0.1,s2-eth1:None,s2-eth2:None,s2-eth3:None pid=29653>
<OVSSwitch{'protocol': 'OpenFlow13'} s3: lo:127.0.0.1,s3-eth1:None,s3-eth2:None,s3-eth3:None pid=29656>
<RemoteController{'ip': '10.5.1.3', 'port': 6633} c0: 10.5.1.3:6633 pid=29633>
```

The flow table in the ovs switch seems to be empty.

```
mininet@mininet-vm:~$ sudo ovs-ofctl  dump-ports s1
OFPST_PORT reply (xid=0x2): 3 ports
  port  1: rx pkts=0, bytes=0, drop=0, errs=0, frame=0, over=0, crc=0
           tx pkts=0, bytes=0, drop=0, errs=0, coll=0
  port  2: rx pkts=0, bytes=0, drop=0, errs=0, frame=0, over=0, crc=0
           tx pkts=0, bytes=0, drop=0, errs=0, coll=0
  port LOCAL: rx pkts=0, bytes=0, drop=0, errs=0, frame=0, over=0, crc=0
           tx pkts=0, bytes=0, drop=0, errs=0, coll=0
mininet@mininet-vm:~$ sudo ovs-ofctl  dump-flows s1
NXST_FLOW reply (xid=0x4):
```

I have installed the features that looks like they are responsible for this, without any success.

```
odl-openflowplugin-flow-services                                │ 0.7.0            │          │ Started     │ odl-openflowplugin-flow-services                                │ OpenDaylight :: Openflow Plugin :: Flow Services
features-openflowplugin                                         │ 0.7.0            │ x        │ Started     │ features-openflowplugin                                         │ features-openflowplugin
odl-openflowplugin-app-lldp-speaker                             │ 0.7.0            │ x        │ Started     │ odl-openflowplugin-app-lldp-speaker                             │ OpenDaylight :: Openflow Plugin :: Application -
odl-openflowplugin-app-topology                                 │ 0.7.0            │          │ Started     │ odl-openflowplugin-app-topology                                 │ OpenDaylight :: Openflow Plugin :: Application -
odl-openflowplugin-app-topology-lldp-discovery
```

please point me in the right direction. All the online questions and answers seems to be aimed at the earlier versions of the ODL Controller. This being a highly used controller, there should be a way to achive this.

Comment: I assume you're using the Fluorine version  - unfortunately the DLUX and l2switch projects are currently not being maintained by anyone and thus did not participate in the Fluorine release cycle. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53109420/problem-when-compiling-the-latest-version-of-l2switch

Comment: Thanks, @TomPantelis. It seems that we can't use l2switch feature unless someone actually starts working on it again. But is there any other feature that I can use to get a reactive flow entry? It seems that I'll have to use an older version of the ODL, which doesn't make sense since ODL is a well-known controller and is extensively used. Maybe I am looking at it the wrong way.

Comment: ODL is also an open source project that needs contributors to keep it going. So yes *someone* has to actually start working on l2switch again and that doesn't happen by magic :) So instead of reverting to an older version, perhaps you would like to contribute and reboot it?