# Why I could not find the l2switch feature in the new opendaylight?

Tags: opendaylight

I downloaded the Opendaylight Fluorine (karaf 0.9.1), I am trying to install the odl-l2switch feature, but it is not showing on the list. was it removed?

Comment: yes, it was removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

l2switch is no longer actively maintained by anyone and thus was not included in the Fluorine release. Also see [Problem when compiling the latest version of l2switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53109420/problem-when-compiling-the-latest-version-of-l2switch)